# Advice on MongoDB Collection Design for Log File Storage

Tags: mongodb

I would like to use MongoDB to store log files generated by production machines at my company. The log files will be associated to a single job number.

A typical log document would look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53bb311703bb72d6eed0af7e"),
    "JobNumber" : 1172,
    "LogTime" : "Tue Dec 03 2013 12:29:16",
    "Operator" : "Bill Smith",
    "RecordNumber" : 100,
    "LogString" : "00001922",
    "State" : "OK",
    "Readings" : "0001DDDD00;7745001"
}
```

Querying the log database would only ever happen within a job. i.e. I would never need to see log files from multiple jobs all at once. I am usually going to be querying for log lines within a given date range, and querying for the existence of "OK" somewhere in the State field.

I am wondering if it is a good idea to design my collections such that each job has its own collection. If not, what are some considerations I need to make in order to get the quickest response time.

Comment: How many jobs will you be expecting?

Comment: One collection per job should be fine then, but until document level locking is brought out (it is due out soon it seems, it is already in the dev branch of MongoDB) you won't gain performance benefits. The biggest performance benefit until then would be one job per database

Comment: But it is very unlikely you need to split these out for performance anyway. It seems more like logical seperation than anything